# How would I turn of notification for a Facebook friend when using mobile web and/or Android app?

Tags: facebook, notifications, mobile, android

I want to turn off notification for updates of one specific Facebook friend using Facebook mobile web/app. How can I do that?

We can have the `Get Notifications` from full version web.

p.s.

A quick [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=How%20would%20I%20turn%20of%20notification%20for%20a%20Facebook%20friend%20when%20using%20mobile%20web%20and%2For%20Android%20app%3F&oq=How%20would%20I%20turn%20of%20notification%20for%20a%20Facebook%20friend%20when%20using%20mobile%20web%20and%2For%20Android%20app%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57.208j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=How%20would%20I%20turn%20off%20notification%20for%20a%20Facebook%20friend%20when%20using%20mobile%20web%20and/or%20Android%20app%3F&start=10) gives me results [01](https://www.facebook.com/help/452400401467000/), [02](http://www.guidingtech.com/19422/disable-facebook-android-notifications-certain-friends/), [03](http://www.itworld.com/answers/topic/mobile-wireless/question/there-way-turn-facebook-notifications-iphone-4s); not very helpful to me though.

[image]

While we can NOT find it in the same place from mobile web and/or Android app.

[image]